# Writing and then reading a string in file encoded in latin1

Tags: python, io, latin1

Here are 2 code samples, Python3 : the first one writes two files with latin1 encoding :

```
s='On écrit ça dans un fichier.'
with open('spam1.txt', 'w',encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
    print(s, file=f)
with open('spam2.txt', 'w',encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

The second one reads the same files with the same encoding :

```
with open('spam1.txt', 'r',encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
    s1=f.read()
with open('spam2.txt', 'r',encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
    s2=f.read()
```

Now, printing s1 and s2 I get

```
On Ã©crit Ã§a dans un fichier.
```

instead of the initial "On écrit ça dans un fichier."

What is wrong ? I also tried with io.open but I miss something. The funny part is that I had no such problem with Python2.7 and its str.decode method which is now gone...

Could someone help me ?

Comment: Are you 100% certain the files were written with Latin-1 encoding? That looks awfully much like UTF-8 data..

Comment: `>>> 'On écrit ça dans un fichier.'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')` gives `'On Ã©crit Ã§a dans un fichier.'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your data was written out as UTF-8:

```
>>> 'On écrit ça dans un fichier.'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
'On Ã©crit Ã§a dans un fichier.'
```

This either means you did not write out Latin-1 data, or your source code was saved as UTF-8 but you declared your script (using a [PEP 263-compliant header](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) to be Latin-1 instead.

If you saved your Python script with a header like:

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

but your text editor saved the file with UTF-8 encoding instead, then the string literal:

```
s='On écrit ça dans un fichier.'
```

will be misinterpreted by Python as well, in the same manner. Saving the resulting unicode value to disk as Latin-1, then reading it again as Latin-1 will preserve the error.

To debug, please take a close look at `print(s.encode('unicode_escape'))` in the *first* script. If it looks like:

```
b'On \\xc3\\xa9crit \\xc3\\xa7a dans un fichier.'
```

then your source code encoding and the PEP-263 header are disagreeing on how the source code should be interpreted. If your source code is correctly decoded the correct output is:

```
b'On \\xe9crit \\xe7a dans un fichier.'
```

If Spyder is stubbornly ignoring the PEP-263 header and reading your source as Latin-1 *regardless*, avoid using non-ASCII characters and use escape codes instead; either using `\uxxxx` unicode code points:

```
s = 'On \u00e9crit \u007aa dans un fichier.'
```

or `\xaa` one-byte escape codes for code-points below 256:

```
s = 'On \xe9crit \x7aa dans un fichier.'
```

Comment: @Coulombeau: without some landmarks, I cannot help you find your way. I gave you an indication on how to debug this. How about you update your question with the output of `s.encode('unicode_escape')` and poke me again?

Comment: Well, I'm lost !
I edited only the first script as you requested.
Made the test `print(s.encode('unicode_escape'))` which gave me the first buggy result you cited.

The decided to add an header (which I hadn't done before) and put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` or tried also ascii or latin1. Nothing changed.

Then I wrote the simple lines (I need to understand, let's take it very simple !) :

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

s='On écrit ça dans un fichier.'

print(s.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))`

which gave me...

On Ã©crit Ã§adans un fichier.

Comment: sorry for the first useless comment, i published it by mistake and then was unable to edit it because 5mins passed

Comment: Your editor is then saving your source code as Latin1 instead.

Comment: Well, can it be a problem xith my distribution ? I'm using Windows 7 with WinPython3.3(64bits). I've not really the choice for the distribution as I'm a teacher and that's the distribution on the computers of the CPGE (french system...) in which I'm teaching. Anyway.

I'm editing with spyder right now. Should I change or maybe edit some configuration file ?

The bad result for `print(s.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))` is really ununderstandable to me...

Comment: That's because `s` *itself* is already incorrect. This is not a problem with your distribution but with how your source code is saved.

Comment: first Hex of my file : 23 20 2D...
which correspond to # -
So the coding of the file should be ANSI or CP1252

but with header 

`# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-` nothing changes...

And I precise that the string is correctly written in the editor or in the console by a `print(s)`

Comment: @Coulombeau: And what does `print(s.encode('unicode_escape'))` tell you about the value?

Comment: Ok, I think it's a bug of Spyder or at least I got an hint.
I executed the very simple code with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as header (because my hex editor gave me c3 c9 for é even if the heading hex for utf8 were missing), then defining `s='On écrit ça dans la console.'` on a second line, and `print(s)` on the third.

With Spyder, I get `On Ã©crit Ã§a dans la console.` in the console window even if the string is alright in the editor window.

Then I loaded and runned the same file (without editing) under IDLE : and the result was correct !

Comment: @Coulombeau: Interesting! Seems Spyder is ignoring the PEP 263 header. You can use `\uxxxx` escapes instead when creating a literal.

Comment: The `print(s.encode('unicode_escape'))` is alright when the script is runned from IDLE, and wrong when runned form Spyder.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I wouldn't have thought about the encoding of my script.py if you hadn't pointed it out !